# Given a multivariate polynomial with even degree, can we find its tightest convex polynomial 'envelop'?

Tags: polynomials, convexity

To be specific, given a multivariate polynomial function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with even degree $2d$, can we construct a convex polynomial function $g$, such that:

1. $\forall \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n, g(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{x}) > 0$
2. $\forall$ polynomial function $h$ that satisfies condition 1., $\int_{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n}h(\mathbf{x})-g(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x} > 0$

Note: In condition 2 I want to make $g$ the 'tightest' convex polynomial. You are also welcome to modify it to other measurement of tightness, like $\|g-f\|<\|h-f\|$ (I have not made sure which one is the best).

If we can construct such a convex polynomial for any polynomial function with $2d$, can we assert its degree?

Comment: Sorry but here there is no convex assumption about $f$ and $f$ should be a polynomial (even deciding its convexity is a NP-hard problem). And I think the polynomial approximation of arbitrary function (non-polynomial) by Taylor expansion cannot make sure the polynomials are convex, even if $f$ is convex. Here my motivation is to find a convex polynomial which is always smaller/larger than a given polynomial, but as tight as possible, so that a good bound can be achieved.

Comment: Checking convexity is NP-hard and you are looking for a constructive answer instead of an existence one. So we should construct with "known to be convex polynomials". Why should we hope them to be tight as in your second condition?